# Given that f(x) is a function satisfying f(1)=1 and for any x belongs to R, f(x+5) >= f(x) + 5 and f(x+1)<=f(x)+1. if g(x) = f(x) +5 - x, find g(2022)

Tags: python

I am struggling to solve this problem,
I couldn't understand the mathmatics to solve this problem, it will be really helpful if anyone can help me with this problem.

Its already 12 hours I am continiously trying to think but its getting out of my head :( please help me.

And I want to solve this using python.

Here is what I am done -

```
def f(x):
  return x

# Define the function g
def g(x):
  return f(x) + 5 - x

# Find g(2022)
g_2022 = g(2022)

# Print the result
print("g(2022) =", g_2022)
```

Comment: The code you posted appears to solve the problem.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: `f(1) = 1` This doesn't necessarily mean `f(x) = x`.

Comment: yes exactly @JohnGordon f(1) = 1 doesn't mean f(x) = x thats why I am struggling to make the use of the other function f(x+5) and f(x+1) what can I do with that, its getting out of my head :(

Comment: @jasonharper , we have to make a use of f(x+5) and f(x+1) it might have some use

Comment: f(x) = x is certainly consistent with all of the constraints, so if there is a unique definition for f, that has to be it, in which case g(x) = 5.  If there is no unique definition for f, then the problem is under-constrained and there is no unique answer.

Comment: `f(1)=1` is given.  Applying `f(x+5) >= f(x) + 5` implies that f(6) is at least 6; on the other hand, applying `f(x+1)<=f(x)+1` five times implies that f(6) is at most 6 - in other words, it must be exactly 6.  Induction will extend this to any value, so `f(x) = x` is the only possible definition of the function.

Comment: @jasonharper That only applies to values that are multiples of 5, plus 1, i.e. 5x + 1.  So f(1) = 1, f(6) = 6, f(11) = 11, etc.  Now show me a proof that f(2) = 2.

Comment: It is not true that f(x) must be x for all x. For example, the function given by f(x) = n if n <= x < n+1 for an integer n satisfies the conditions as well. It is true though that any function satisfying these conditions we will give f(n)  = n for any integer n.